# Can I Change the Gnome 3.10 Workspace Grid?

Tags: ubuntu, workspace, gnome-3, virtual-desktop

I really like Gnome 3 but I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and installed Gnome 3.10.1. Before I could just turn on the extension "Workspace Grid" and be set. Now it shows that this extension is out of date. Is there any other way to configure Gnome 3 to use CTRL+ALT+(Any arrow direction) as a shortcut for changing workspaces?

(Take a look at the link to see what I am referring to. I want the workspace grid to be 2 high and three wide)

[Screenshot of Workspace Grid Extension in use](https://extensions.gnome.org/static/extension-data/screenshots/screenshot_484.png)

Answer (score 9):

There is an update for this extension by migerh. You can download it here:

https://bitbucket.org/migerh/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/downloads

Download `workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com-for-3.10.1.zip` and extract it to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

You might want to restart Gnome by pressing `Alt+F2`, then typing `r` and hitting `Return`. I didn't figure out how to get the new extension version to be recognized without this.

You should now be able to activate the Workspace Grid extension as usual.

You should also enable static workspaces in gnome-tweak-tool to take full advantage of the extension, if you haven't already: Start Tweak Tool, go to the Workspaces tab, and set "Workspace Creation" to "Static" and the "Number of Workspaces" to your desired number (6).

Now you just have to pay a little attention when the original extension by mathematicalcoffe is updated. When that happens, you probably want to switch back to the "official" version.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but I still use workspace grid on the regular, and I'm sure many others do as well.

To follow up on toster's answer -- you may need to edit the metadata.json file located in the .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/[grid-workspace] folder. Simply change the gnome shell version to the version you are running.

Alt-F2, r, and hopefully your "outdated" grid workspace extension will be up and running again.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not mind the bottom task bar, this addon has grid functionality.

http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/extensions/index.html

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/